# AJAX POST request with response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

As the title states, I'm looking to make a POST request using JavaScript and also get a response. Here's my current code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'test.php', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success
    console.log(request.responseText)
  } else {
    // Server-side Error
    console.log("Server-side Error")
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
    // Connection Error
    console.log("Connection Error")
};

request.send({
    'color':'red', 
    'food': 'carrot',
    'animal': 'crow'
});
```

With test.php being:

```
<?php 
    echo $_POST['color'];
?>
```

This should return 'red' but instead returns nothing.

This seems like a simple problem but I could only find solutions for people using jQuery. I'd like a solution that does not rely on and libraries.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: **Warning**: `$_REQUEST` can be populated by the query string, post data or cookies. Naming conflicts (especially when cookies are involved) can cause confusion. It is best avoided in favour of the more explicit superglobals `$_COOKIES`, `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is vulnerable to XSS - I put this together quickly because I did not want to upload my real code.

Comment: All of the current solutions simply log the source code of "test.php" to the console as opposed to logging 'red' to the console.

Comment: That's a another issue and unrelated to your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Answer (score 0):

The `send` method takes a string rather than an object, perhaps more like:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    console.log(request.response)
  } else {
    console.log("Server-side Error")
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
    console.log("Connection Error")
};

request.open('POST', 'test.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.send('color=red&food=carrot&animal=crow');
```

Comment: Huh. I thought that this would work but it still gives me nothing.

Comment: This leaves the request content-type as `text/plain` so PHP doesn't know how to decode it and `$_REQUEST` isn't populated. You could set the Content-Type manually, but FormData is a better approach.

Comment: good spot @Quentin ~ tested and found no response... added header - boom!

Answer (score 0):

## The JavaScript problem

You are trying to send a generic Object, so it gets converted to a String (`"[Object object]"`), and the data is lost.

Convert the data to a FormData object instead.

```
var data = {
    'color':'red', 
    'food': 'carrot',
    'animal': 'crow'
};

var formData = new FormData();

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) { 
  formData.append(key, data[key]);
})

request.send(formData);
```

## The PHP problem

> All of the current solutions simply log the source code of "test.php" to the console as opposed to logging 'red' to the console

This is an issue unrelated to your code. It is also a FAQ. See: [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: @073148974301870437087 — It works perfectly when I test it: http://i.imgur.com/qFAdiU7.png

Comment: I can't reproduce that.

Comment: Hun. I guess I'll be doing more research to see if I can fix this problem. Thanks for all the help, hopefully I'll get things to work.